# Struggles with loop

Tags: java

I'm working on LinkedList assignment and noob in Java. Appreciate all the help.

```
    Record obj;

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        obj = (Record) it.next();
        if (obj.number == number) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + obj.name);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No such Number exists");
```

--> Moving this statement above is just resulting in printing "No such Number exists" x times of the loop. How do I overcome this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddressBook myContacts = new AddressBook();
    myContacts.add("John", 9876123450l);
    myContacts.add("Mellisa", 8360789114l);
    myContacts.add("Daman",9494149900l);
    myContacts.findByNumber(9998760333l);  
    myContacts.findByNumber(9494149900l);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    Successfully added:John
    Successfully added:Mellisa
    Successfully added:Daman
    No such Number exists
    Name: Daman
```

**Code output**

```
    Successfully added:John
    Successfully added:Mellisa
    Successfully added:Daman
    No such Number exists
    Name: Daman
    No such Number exists
```

Comment: It is obvious, you are printing `No such Number exists` regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember case when you have found a user:

```java
Record obj;

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    boolean userFound = false;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        obj = (Record) it.next();
        if (obj.number == number) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + obj.name);
            userFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!userFound) {
        System.out.println("No such Number exists"); 
    }
```